# How can I set which Google calendars are being synced to my iPhone?

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization, iphone

I've set up my iPhone (with iOS 5.1.1) to synchronize contacts and calendars from Google via Google Mail.

However, I only see the *Default* calendar on my iPhone, whereas all my other private calendars from Google Calendar are missing as an option.

A couple of months ago, there used to be `http://m.google.com/sync`, as [explained here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1156541/sync_google_calendars.html), but it doesn't appear to exist anymore.

Where can I select those calendars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option still exists, but the new URL is:

> https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect

Here, you can enable all calendars that exist.

Comment: The link posted by slhck is not correct either, as that only applies to CalDAV synced accounts. The original poster (and me) are trying to use an Exchange based sync. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: I had made a mistake there – I was using the "normal" Google Mail account for calendars all along (I am the original poster). Only Contacts were synced using Exchange. In the meantime, I've switched to CardDAV though.